# Generate ECPublicKey in java

Tags: java, keystore, public-key-encryption

I am new to java ecc encryption. So I got ECC public key data array from java card.the size is 49 byte length. So I need to generate Eccpublic key. So I have created public key. but it gives error:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: encoded key spec not recognised

This is my code. How to generate Eccpublickey using data array?

```
byte[] pub = new byte[] {
    /*(Public data) 49 length byte ARRAY
    */


     };

    System.out.println("Length :" + pub.length);
    X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pub);

    KeyFactory kf;
    try {
        kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH");

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    ECPublicKey remotePublicKey;

    try {
        remotePublicKey = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(ks);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(remotePublicKey);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the actual data in the data array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is the code not working the keyspec can't use in ECC.so i found how to use `ECPublicKeySpec` in ECC.In here it has good explanation.https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2899.0;wap2 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Card key is encoded in plain text form. I tried to use mostly plain Java, but the decoding process from the byte array representation requires still BouncyCastle's `ECPointUtil`. Maybe there is a built-in way to do this, but I have not come across one.

The format is simple: It starts with `04` and then the `x`, `y` coordinates are each on 32 bytes and can be used with a positive `BigInteger` when e.g. `secp256r1` is used.

Example:

> 042b495a9b4142dc317624626ad108d4896c12a97af1a1372e9a7b0f29adcaeb49dee377c97fbb17b61480e857f5ce72408488e2763619159d032d3be091266dd6

```java
BigInteger x = new BigInteger(1, pubKey, 1, 32)
BigInteger y = new BigInteger(1, pubKey, 32, 32)
```

The tricky part is the use of `AlgorithmParameters` which is simple but in general an unknown API.

```java
ECGenParameterSpec ecGenParameterSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1");
AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
algorithmParameters.init(ecGenParameterSpec);
ECParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = algorithmParameters.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);
ECPoint point = ECPointUtil.decodePoint(ecParameterSpec.getCurve(), pubKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
ECPublicKeySpec ecPublicKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, ecParameterSpec);
ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(ecPublicKeySpec);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445997/loading-raw-64-byte-long-ecdsa-public-key-in-java  which includes your Bouncy ECPointUtil method and several others.