# Loading raw 64-byte long ECDSA public key in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key, ecdsa

I have a raw (r,s) format ECDSA NIST P-256 public key. It seems that there is no simple way to load it into an object that implements java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey.

What is the cleanest way to load a 64 byte public key so that it can be used to check signatures?

Comment: What's the format of your EC Public Key? Compressed or uncompressed?

Comment: 64 bytes? Obviously not compressed. It would be 33 bytes if it was compressed.

Comment: Correct. It is uncompressed.

Comment: An ECDSA **public key** is a point (on the relevant curve) and an uncompressed point's **components are x and y** which are elements of the underlying field i.e. Fp; r and s are the components of a _signature_ and are elements of Zn where n is not p, although the NIST Fp curves have cofactor 1 so n is the order of the curve which is fairly _near_ p per Hasse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Java 7 is required for the EC functionality and Java 8 for the Base 64 encoder / decoder, no additional libraries - just plain Java. Note that this will actually display the public key as a *named curve* when printed out, something most other solutions won't do. *If you have an up-to-date runtime, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56170785/589259) is more clean.*

This answer is going to be tough if we do this using `ECPublicKeySpec`. So lets cheat a bit and use `X509EncodedKeySpec` instead:

```
private static byte[] P256_HEAD = Base64.getDecoder().decode("MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE");

/**
 * Converts an uncompressed secp256r1 / P-256 public point to the EC public key it is representing.
 * @param w a 64 byte uncompressed EC point consisting of just a 256-bit X and Y
 * @return an <code>ECPublicKey</code> that the point represents 
 */
public static ECPublicKey generateP256PublicKeyFromFlatW(byte[] w) throws InvalidKeySpecException {
    byte[] encodedKey = new byte[P256_HEAD.length + w.length];
    System.arraycopy(P256_HEAD, 0, encodedKey, 0, P256_HEAD.length);
    System.arraycopy(w, 0, encodedKey, P256_HEAD.length, w.length);
    KeyFactory eckf;
    try {
        eckf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("EC key factory not present in runtime");
    }
    X509EncodedKeySpec ecpks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
    return (ECPublicKey) eckf.generatePublic(ecpks);
}
```

Usage:

```
ECPublicKey key = generateP256PublicKeyFromFlatW(w);
System.out.println(key);
```

---

The idea behind this is to create a temporary X509 encoded key, which happily ends with the public point `w` at the end. The bytes before that contain the ASN.1 DER encoding of the OID of the named curve and structural overhead, ending with byte `04` indicating an uncompressed point. [Here is an example](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAg) what the structure looks like, using value 1 and 2 for the 32-byte X and Y.

The 32-byte X and Y values of the uncompressed point values removed to create the header. This only works because the point is statically sized - it's location at the end is only determined by the size of the curve.

Now all that is required in the function `generateP256PublicKeyFromFlatW` is to add the received public point `w` to the header and run it through the decoder implemented for `X509EncodedKeySpec`.

---

The above code uses a raw, uncompressed public EC point - just a 32 byte X and Y - without the uncompressed point indicator with value `04`. Of course it is easy to support 65 byte compressed points as well:

```
/**
 * Converts an uncompressed secp256r1 / P-256 public point to the EC public key it is representing.
 * @param w a 64 byte uncompressed EC point starting with <code>04</code>
 * @return an <code>ECPublicKey</code> that the point represents 
 */
public static ECPublicKey generateP256PublicKeyFromUncompressedW(byte[] w) throws InvalidKeySpecException {
    if (w[0] != 0x04) {
        throw new InvalidKeySpecException("w is not an uncompressed key");
    }
    return generateP256PublicKeyFromFlatW(Arrays.copyOfRange(w, 1, w.length));
}
```

---

Finally, I generated the constant `P256_HEAD` head value in base 64 using:

```
private static byte[] createHeadForNamedCurve(String name, int size)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    ECGenParameterSpec m = new ECGenParameterSpec(name);
    kpg.initialize(m);
    KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    byte[] encoded = kp.getPublic().getEncoded();
    return Arrays.copyOf(encoded, encoded.length - 2 * (size / Byte.SIZE));
}
```

called by:

```
String name = "NIST P-256";
int size = 256;
byte[] head = createHeadForNamedCurve(name, size);
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(head));
```

Answer (score 9):

> What is the cleanest way to load a 64 byte public key so that it can be used to check signatures?

The cleanest I could muster ! Should work with other curves too..

**NOTE: Limited to the SunJCE provider or Android API 26+ (there may be more providers with this functionality, I am unaware of them at the moment.**

```
public static ECPublicKey rawToEncodedECPublicKey(String curveName, byte[] rawBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidParameterSpecException {
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    byte[] x = Arrays.copyOfRange(rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.length/2);
    byte[] y = Arrays.copyOfRange(rawBytes, rawBytes.length/2, rawBytes.length);
    ECPoint w = new ECPoint(new BigInteger(1,x), new BigInteger(1,y));
    return (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(new ECPublicKeySpec(w, ecParameterSpecForCurve(curveName)));
}

public static ECParameterSpec ecParameterSpecForCurve(String curveName) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidParameterSpecException {
    AlgorithmParameters params = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("EC");
    params.init(new ECGenParameterSpec(curveName));
    return params.getParameterSpec(ECParameterSpec.class);
}
```

Comment: Interesting trick for generating the parameters. I presume this also allows you to keep using the named parameters rather than the explicit ones? Definitely less hacked than my answer anyway. Any prerequisites for this answer?

Comment: It's less hacked when it's available... parametrizing your answer to support other curves is a nice middle ground.

Answer (score 6):

Java does make cryptography very long winded.

The procedure to create a public key from a given EC point:

1. Construct an `ECPoint` object from your given co-ordinates.
2. Construct an `ECParameterSpec` object from information of your curve.
3. Construct an `ECPublicKeySpec` object from your `ECPoint` and your `ECParameterSpec` object.
4. Invoke `KeyFactory.generatePublic()` with your `ECPublicKeySpec` object to retrieve a `PublicKey` object.
5. Cast the `PublicKey` into an `ECPublicKey` as necessary.

Example below:

```
// Setup for P-256 curve params

BigInteger p256_p = new BigInteger("ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff", 16);

BigInteger p256_a = new BigInteger("ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc", 16);
BigInteger p256_b = new BigInteger("5ac635d8aa3a93e7b3ebbd55769886bc651d06b0cc53b0f63bce3c3e27d2604b", 16);
byte[] p256_seed = {
                        (byte) 0xc4, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0x08, 
                        (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x93, 
                        (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0xe1, 
                        (byte) 0x13, (byte) 0x9d, (byte) 0x26, (byte) 0xb7, 
                        (byte) 0x81, (byte) 0x9f, (byte) 0x7e, (byte) 0x90
                    };

BigInteger p256_xg = new BigInteger("6b17d1f2e12c4247f8bce6e563a440f277037d812deb33a0f4a13945d898c296", 16);
BigInteger p256_yg = new BigInteger("4fe342e2fe1a7f9b8ee7eb4a7c0f9e162bce33576b315ececbb6406837bf51f5", 16);

BigInteger p256_n = new BigInteger("ffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffffbce6faada7179e84f3b9cac2fc632551", 16);

// Construct prime field
ECFieldFp p256_field = new ECFieldFp(p256_p);

// Construct curve from parameters
EllipticCurve p256 = new EllipticCurve(p256_field, p256_a, p256_b, p256_seed);

// Construct base point for curve
ECPoint p256_base = new ECPoint(p256_xg, p256_yg);

// Construct curve parameter specifications object
ECParameterSpec p256spec = new ECParameterSpec(p256, p256_base, p256_n, 1); // Co-factor 1 for prime curves

// ------------------------------------------------------------- //

// Construct EC point from "raw" public key
ECPoint point = new ECPoint(r, s); // r, s is of type BigInteger

// Create a EC public key specification object from point and curve
ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(point, p256spec);

// Retrieve EC KeyFactory
KeyFactory ECFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");

// Generate public key via KeyFactory
PublicKey pubKey = ECFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
ECPublicKey ECPubKey = (ECPublicKey) pubKey;
```

It may be helpful to generate the ECParameterSpec once (perhaps in a static initializer block) for performance reasons.

Note: There is probably a much simpler way to generate the ECParameterSpec object (via named curves for example) but so far I've only found that `ECGenParameterSpec` has this feature. Let me know in comments if there is a less painful approach.

---

To save yourself the pain of doing the above, encode your EC key under X.509, which will fully describe the key **and** make loading it much much easier.

In java, with the ECPublicKey, all you need to do is call `ECPublicKey.getEncoded()` and pass/save the byte array to where you need the key next. The X.509 encoded key can then be reconstructed via:

```
// Retrieve EC KeyFactory
KeyFactory ECFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");

// Generate public key via KeyFactory
PublicKey pubKey = ECFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(data));
ECPublicKey ECPubKey = (ECPublicKey) pubKey;
```

where "data" is the encoded byte array.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Well it did take longer than I expected to actually get all the constants used in the curve, grabbing them from two or three different documents. I'm still surprised java doesn't have a straightforward way to obtain the ECParameterSpec object directly from named curves, seems like a very useful function if it existed.

Comment: You're definitely right about that. Happy to support a feature request :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Where did you get the constants? In particular the p256_seed?

Comment: @user1094206 They're all available online in publicly published documents. I got most of the information from [this](https://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/ecdsa.pdf) document here but used some supporting documents for the other constants.

Answer (score 6):

That worked for me with the help of Bouncycastle:

```
ECParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1");
ECNamedCurveSpec params = new ECNamedCurveSpec("secp256r1", spec.getCurve(), spec.getG(), spec.getN());
ECPoint publicPoint =  ECPointUtil.decodePoint(params.getCurve(), publicKeyByteArray);
ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(publicPoint, params);
PublicKey publicKey =  keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
```

Comment: This relies on BouncyCastle, which is not automatically present (except on Android in the form of spongycastle).

Comment: Yes, updated the answer. It seemed to me the most straightforward solution to get a java.security.PublicKey

Answer (score 3):

The EC Public Key is a point that consists of x and y co-ordinate. I wrote the following code segment once to convert EC x, y point to `publicKey` object. Hope this will help you.
For your information:

> rawPubKey = 04 + x co-ordinate + y co-ordinate (Hex String)
>
> curveName = P-256 (String)

Example EC Public Key Point for P-256:

> rawPubKey = 04 6B17D1F2E12C4247F8BCE6E563A440F277037D812DEB33A0F4A13945D898C296 4FE342E2FE1A7F9B8EE7EB4A7C0F9E162BCE33576B315ECECBB6406837BF51F5

**BC Provider:** You need Bouncy Castle provider. I used **bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar**, but you can download the latest version from [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

```
/**
 * This method converts the uncompressed raw EC public key into java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey
 * @param rawPubKey 
 * @param curveName
 * @return java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey
 */
public ECPublicKey ucPublicKeyToPublicKey(String rawPubKey, String curveName) {
    byte[] rawPublicKey = Helper.toByte(rawPubKey); 
    ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = null;
    KeyFactory kf = null;
    
    ECNamedCurveParameterSpec ecNamedCurveParameterSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(curveName);
    ECCurve curve = ecNamedCurveParameterSpec.getCurve();
    EllipticCurve ellipticCurve = EC5Util.convertCurve(curve, ecNamedCurveParameterSpec.getSeed());
    java.security.spec.ECPoint ecPoint = ECPointUtil.decodePoint(ellipticCurve, rawPublicKey);
    ECParameterSpec ecParameterSpec = EC5Util.convertSpec(ellipticCurve, ecNamedCurveParameterSpec);
    java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec(ecPoint, ecParameterSpec);
    
    kf = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    
    try {
        ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Caught Exception public key: " + e.toString());
    }
    
    return ecPublicKey;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is `toByte()` method:

```
public static byte[] toByte(String hex) {
        if (hex == null)
            return null;
        hex = hex.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        byte[] buffer = null;
        if (hex.length() % 2 != 0) {
            hex = "0" + hex;
        }
        int len = hex.length() / 2;
        buffer = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(
                    hex.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
        }
        return buffer;
    }
```

But you can use your own implementation. Here is another one:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
public static byte[] toByte(String hex) {{
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hex);
}
```

Comment: Please at least tell people what libraries you are using and what helper functions like `Helper.toByte` do (and why they are needed in the first place).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I edited my answer. Ty. I thought OP can use his own way (helper or builtin library) to convert a `hex string` into `byte array`. :)

Comment: OK, but that's not a well named method - I could not see that it was hex, although I had my suspicions. `ECNamedCurveTable` seems to be a Bouncy Calstle defined class, right?

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to avoid using bouncycastle for various reasons.