# Importing ANSI X9.63 formatted key pair in Java

Tags: java, ios, swift, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I have generated a key pair on iOS and created a data representation using the following code:

```swift
var publicKey, privateKey: SecKey?
let keyattribute = [
    kSecAttrKeyType as String: kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String : 256
    ] as CFDictionary
SecKeyGeneratePair(keyattribute, &publicKey, &privateKey)

var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
let pubkeyRep = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(publicKey!, &error) as Data?
let prikeyRep = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(privateKey!, &error) as Data?
```

According to the documentation from Apple, the [SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1643698-seckeycopyexternalrepresentation) function encodes these keys using uncompressed *[ANSI X9.63 format](https://standards.globalspec.com/std/26827/X9.63)*

I want to transform these byte arrays into `PublicKey` and `PrivateKey` objects in Java.

A few examples that I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56170785/459349) (using SunJCE) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033552/459349) (using BouncyCastle) work for the public key, but they don't describe a way to import the private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice in the Apple documentation how the first 65-bytes are the uncompressed public key (`04 || X || Y`) concatenated with the private scalar (`|| K`). Take these bytes off and you can create the private key. I hope this helps somebody.

```java
/*
 *  For an elliptic curve private key, the output is formatted as the public key
 * concatenated with the big endian encoding of the secret scalar, or 04 || X || Y || K.
 */
private PrivateKey createECPrivateKey(byte[] rawBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidParameterSpecException {
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    BigInteger s = new BigInteger(Arrays.copyOfRange(rawBytes, 65, rawBytes.length));
    return kf.generatePrivate(new ECPrivateKeySpec(s, ecParameterSpecForCurve("secp256r1")));
}
```