# Android generated KeyPair is longer than (server-generated) openssl-generated

Tags: android, security, encryption, openssl, ecdh

To generate an ECDH keypair I have written below code which is the same as server's one which is using open-ssl. But my public key to Hex is like this (176):

```
3056301006072a8648ce3d020106052b8104000a0342000462bf4308171cffa3a3ed74a9e72cd3d5fde26d760322a5e39cd67166240f75f87edaffa52bef5e0895a37751f5b90b7b8fc077a90d76893e7cb857c1a49e4818
```

And  the server public key is shorter, like this (130):

```
041f13436e59b8a4e61952b1f184052b330977732f7f8a0505c46028da82bdafd34ded7444a19acdbbf5de91cd914437c3ac9b827dac2f899a4bba961fd72a7ea3
```

Code:

```
        KeyPairGenerator kpgen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
        ECGenParameterSpec genspec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
        kpgen.initialize(genspec);
```

What's the cause of this discrepancy? Iuse this line to turn public key into byte array:

```
kpgen.generateKeyPair().getPublic().getEncoded()).getBytes();
```

I tried to convert Android-generated public key by:

```
PublicKey pub = kpgen.generateKeyPair().getPublic();    
byte[] pubBytes = pub.getEncoded();
SubjectPublicKeyInfo spkInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(pubBytes);
ASN1Primitive primitive = spkInfo.parsePublicKey();
byte[] publicKeyPKCS1 = primitive.getEncoded();
```

But I get this error:

> java.io.EOFException: DEF length 126 object truncated by 63
> 2021-04-01 17:52:56.113 20381-24882/ at  org.spongycastle.asn1.DefiniteLengthInputStream.toByteArray(DefiniteLengthInputStream.java:103)
> 2021-04-01 17:52:56.113 20381-24882/... W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.createPrimitiveDERObject(ASN1InputStream.java:455)
> 2021-04-01 17:52:56.113 20381-24882/... W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.buildObject(ASN1InputStream.java:190)
> 2021-04-01 17:52:56.113 20381-24882/... W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readObject(ASN1InputStream.java:278)
> 2021-04-01 17:52:56.113 20381-24882/... W/System.err:     at org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.parsePublicKey(SubjectPublicKeyInfo.java:112)

Comment: These are simply two different key formats. The upper public key _305630..._ is in X.509/SPKI format (s. https://lapo.it/asn1js), the lower _041f13..._ is an uncompressed public key (04 + x + y).

Comment: How can I convert the first one into the other?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: You can cast the public key `kpgen.generateKeyPair().getPublic()` to `ECPublicKey` and then you can get the x and y coordinates. Since you also use SpongyCastle, you can apply `java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey` or `org.spongycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey` (with different names regarding x and y coordinate). The uncompressed key results as 0x04 | x | y. Note that the compressed public key is not the same as the X.509/SPKI key ([here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/185552)).

Comment: But with having X, Y ow do I get to X.509 format to send to server? Sorry I think I didn't understand you.

Comment: Your first posted key is in X.509/SPKI format. You asked how to convert the first format (X.509/SPKI) to the second (uncompressed). Now you seem to need the opposite direction. This is described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56170785).

Comment: Sorry, I got it mixed up. Now I casted my X.509/SPKI key to uncomressed format by: `ECPublicKey pub = (ECPublicKey) kpgen.generateKeyPair().getPublic();` But I still have the same length for new Public Key.

Comment: Which `ECPublicKey` did you use, from `java.security.interfaces` or from `org.spongycastle.jce.interfaces`? Anyway, with `getW()` or `getQ()` you can get the `ECPoint` that represents the public key, and thus the x and y coordinates.

Comment: I used both and had the same results. Can you explain more on converting from getW , getQ to ECPoint? Is there a better solution?

Comment: `getW()` and `getQ()` already return an `ECPoint` (`java.security.spec` and `org.spongycastle.math.ec` respectively), so nothing to convert here. Both types have methods (e.g. `getAffineX()` or `getAffineXCoord()`) that return types (`BigInteger` or `ECFieldElement`) that encapsulate the x or y coordinate and methods that return these coordinates as hex string (e.g. `toString(16)`) or as `byte[]` (`getEncoded()`). You then only need to concatenate the parts (0x04 | x | y). A quick and dirty solution is: The last 65 bytes of the X.509/SPKI key are the uncompressed key.

Comment: So how come the uncompressed has 130 members an not 65? exactly twice?

Comment: The uncompressed key (for secp256k1) consists of 65 bytes. If it is encoded as a hex string it has 130 bytes, since each byte is represented by two characters and thus two bytes (i.e. in the hex encoded X509/SPKI key the last 130 characters represent the uncompressed hex encoded key).

Comment: Thank you! I got it. Really appreciate it!